# Is it okay grammatically?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

> Tall animals, for example, a elephant weighs 100kg at least.

Or, should I only use the plural of the word elephant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following:

> Tall animals, such as the elephant, weigh at least 100 kg.

When we speak of an animal as a type in a formal or scientific context, it's common to say "the elephant", "the zebra", etc.

[Here's an example.](https://www.reference.com/pets-animals/elephants-symbolize-11a36c8c7aecb9a3)

If you want more understanding of article use, try [this link](http://advice.writing.utoronto.ca/english-language/articles/).

The information which follows is not absolutely important to understand thoroughly, but I'm including it in case you want to know more.

I prefer using the "such as" form, rather than "for example", because "such as" is smoother inside a sentence.  You can use "for example", but it's usually either at the beginning of a phrase or it feels more like a break in the sentence.

Here are a couple examples of how "for example" might be used naturally:

> Tall animals (for example, the elephant) weigh at least 100 kg.
>
> Tall animals -- for example, the elephant -- weigh at least 100 kg.

The following is probably acceptable to most, but it feels unnatural to me.  (I'm a reasonably literate American native speaker.)

> Tall animals, for example, the elephant, weight at least 100 kg.

(Yes, I realize that in this day and age there is a bit of irony in the phrase "reasonably literate American", but you get the idea.)

The reason it feels unnatural is that there's too much of a break of the main idea, so it's a [parenthesis](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/parenthesis.htm) which feels better with punctuation marks indicating more of a break from the main idea.

Answer (score 1):

It should read:

> "Tall animals, for example, **an** elephant, **weigh** 100kg at
>   least."

Everything else is fine.  The plural is unnecessary.  You have to make the subject and verb agree.  "Tall animals" is the subject and "weigh" is its verb.